# how to set the height of subtitle in highchart without defining height of the container?

Tags: highcharts

I am using highchart's pie chart to display my data. But i am having some problem on setting the height of the sub-title. I am displaying my chart in a div named container(`<div id="container></div>`). However, the height i have to set is inside that div which is set by highchart itself. My subtitle is quite long and is not fully displayed in the chart.

I have made the js fiddle of my issue below:

http://jsfiddle.net/Simron_Thapa/eezpjaav/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explicitly bump up the height of the created `highcharts-container`:

```
        var elem = $('.highcharts-container');
        elem.css('height',elem.height() + 200); // increasing it by 200px
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eezpjaav/1/).